# Comparing two NSDates returning 0 or equal

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-comparison

I am facing problem in comparing two `NSDates`. I am not getting proper value, where I am going wrong.

First I compared using `compare` method of `NSDate` which was returning 0 and next I tried to convert it into float by calling `timeIntervalSince1970` which is giving same output.
What I am doing wrong, I am not getting.

Here is the simple try which I did.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];

NSString *date1String = @"01/01/2016";
NSString *date2String = @"03/01/2016";

float date1 = [[formatter dateFromString:date1String] timeIntervalSince1970];
float date2 = [[formatter dateFromString:date2String] timeIntervalSince1970];

if (date1 > date2) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");

} else if (date1 < date2){
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");

} else {
    NSLog(@"date1 is Equal date2 %f \n%f",date1,date2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your date formate is wrong, it should be `dd/MM/yyyy` also use `compare` to compare to `NSDate` objects.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString *date1String = @"01/01/2016";
NSString *date2String = @"03/01/2016";

NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:date1String];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:date2String];
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, YYYY was the problem.
It is showing now properly. :)

Comment: If you doesn't change YYYY to yyyy you will not get proper date.

Comment: Don't use double, use NSTimerInterval. And update the answer with the proper date format.

Comment: @SahebSingh If you use `YYYY` both date1 and date2 contain same value `1450549800` which is wrong, if you use `yyyy`, you get `1451586600` for date1 and `1451759400` for `date2` which is correct one.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for correcting me, i am literally saying date formate is wrong and suggesting correct one and still using the wrong one.